# Need help fixing face drawing program

Tags: python

Every time I run the program, I get an error saying 'int object has no attribute clone'. I keep on getting the same error no matter what I try. I'm very very new to python by the way which might actually be easy to tell from looking at my code lol.

```
# draw.py
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin('faces', 400, 400)
win.setCoords(0, 0, 400, 400)

def drawFace():
    Head = Circle(Point(250, 250), 40)
    Head.setFill("peachpuff")
    Head.setOutline("black")

    RightEye = Circle(Point(270, 260), 5)
    RightEye.setFill("blue")
    RightEye.setOutline("black")

    LeftEye = Circle(Point(240, 260), 5)
    LeftEye.setFill("blue")
    LeftEye.setOutline("black")

    Mouth = Rectangle(Point(250, 240), 10)
    Mouth.setFill("pink")
    Mouth.setOutline("black")

    Head.draw(win)
    RightEye.draw(win)
    LeftEye.draw(win)
    Mouth.draw(win)

drawFace()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the graphics.py module available at http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/, or at least something with that same interface...

```
Mouth = Rectangle(Point(250, 240), 10)
```

[`Rectangle`](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node8.html) doesn't take a point and an integer, it takes two points. If you want to draw a square that's ten units on each side, try:

```
Mouth = Rectangle(Point(250, 240), Point(260, 250))
```

It may or may not also be necessary to add a line to pause execution, such as `input("Press Enter to conintue.")` at the end of the program, depending on how you're running your file. IDLE will keep the window open regardless, but on the command line it will close nearly immediately.

Now you should see your face:

[image]